# How to check active connections in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

All connection are in LAN.

I want to know IP Adresess and if it is possible toogether with ProcessID of All active connection (to all databases).
How to check active connections in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) for this. – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822